# Is the subspace $N=\{y\in l_\infty: y_k=x_k\ a.a.k,\ x\in M \}$ closed or not?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis, density-function

Let $l_\infty$ be the set of all bounded real sequences.

$S:l_\infty\to l_\infty$ be the shift operator defined by $S(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots)=(x_2,x_3,x_4,\dots)$ for all $x\in l_\infty$

Let $M=\{x-Sx:x\in l_\infty\}$. Then it is clear to me that $M$ is a linear subspace of $l_\infty$.

For a subset $P$ of $\mathbb N$ the natural/asymptotic density is defined by the limit (if it exists)$$\delta(P)=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{|P\cap\{1,2,\dots,n\}|}{n}$$

We say a condition $\mathcal C$ is satisfied by $x_k\ a.a.k$ (for almost all k)
iff $E=\{k\in\mathbb N:x_k$ does not satisfy condition $\mathcal C$ $\}\implies\delta(E)=0$.

Let $N=\{y\in l_\infty: y_k=x_k\ a.a.k,\ x\in M \}$.
Then $N$ is a linear subspace of $l_\infty$. So, $M\subset N\subset l_\infty$.

**My question :** Is the subspace $N$ closed in $l_\infty$ or not?

Comment: I am pretty sure that $M$ is not closed. Maybe you should check this first. Also, in your definition of $N$, do you mean "for some $x \in M$", or what?

Comment: @PhoemueX You may show here that $M$ is not closed. It may help me to develop my answer.

Comment: @PhoemueX Yes.   $N=\{y\in l_\infty: y_k=x_k\ a.a.k,$ for some $\ x\in M \}$.

Comment: What topology do you consider on $l_\infty$? It is pointwise convergence (same as subspace of the product of countably many copies of $\Bbb R$ with the product topology), or, more likely the topology generated by the norm $||x||=\sup_k|x_k|$?

Comment: $N$ is not closed if "a.a. $k$" is understood in the sense "for all but finitely many $k$". With your notion of "a.a. $k$" I don't have any idea.

Comment: @Mirko Yes. sup-norm.